# Form adding value from answer twice

Tags: javascript, html

I am developing a form the should show a different result depending on your final score. Currently, it just shows the added score at the bottom and ONLY updates when you click on any of the radio inputs (Q1 or Q2).

While adding all values from the questions, if you fill in both Question 1 and Question 2, Question 3's value is doubled.

I assume it's something in the javascript function but how can I fix it?

https://jsfiddle.net/8rpqp8dm/7/

```
<body>
  <div class="q1 question">
    <h4 class="question">1. Com que frequência tem perdas de urina? (Escolha uma opção):</h4>
      <form>
        <label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="0"> Nunca</label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="1"> Uma vez por semana ou menos</label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="2"> Duas ou três vezes por semana</label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="3"> Uma vez por dia</label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="4"> Várias vezes por dia</label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="5"> Constantemente</label>
      </form>
  </div>
  <div class="q2 question">
    <h4 class="question">2. Gostaríamos de saber a quantidade de urina que acha que perde.<br>Que quantidade de urina costuma perder?<br>(Quer use ou não protecção) (Escolha uma opção)</h4>
      <form>
        <label><input type="radio" name="q2" value="0"> Nenhuma</label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="q2" value="2"> Uma quantidade pequena</label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="q2" value="4"> Uma quantidade moderada</label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="q2" value="6"> Uma grande quantidade</label>
      </form>
  </div>
  <div class="q3 question">
    <h4 class="question">3. No geral, a perda de urina interfere muito no seu dia-a-dia?<br>Escolha entre 0 (nada) e 10 (bastante)</h4>
      <form>
        <input type="range" name="q3" id="q3" value="5" min="0" max="10" oninput="cOut.value = q3.value" style="width: 300px;"><br>
        <output name="cOutName" id="cOut">5</output>
      </form>
  </div>


  <div class="result"></div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    /* ADDING VALUES */
    var $inputs = $('.question input[type=radio]').on('change', function() {
        var total = 0;
        $inputs.filter(':checked').each(function() {
            total += +this.value;
            total += +document.getElementById('q3').value;
        })

        $('.result').text(total);
    });

  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

total += +document.getElementById('q3').value;

you are using this line in each function so it will take the value of q3 for each checked option.

try this:-

```
var $inputs = $('.question input[type=radio]').on('change', function() {
        var total = 0;
        var q3 = document.getElementById('q3').value;
        $inputs.filter(':checked').each(function() {
            total += +this.value;

        });
        total += +q3 ;

        $('.result').text(total);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your q3 value is being doubled because when you have both questions checked, the loop to add the values of q1 and q2 to q3 is running twice as there are two checked items.

To solve this, pull this line:
    total += +document.getElementById('q3').value;

Out of the 'checked' loop and place it underneath.

Hope that helps!